# how to find your project current versions in grails

Tags: grails

I  want to know the versions of the software used while developing the project, Suppose If there is  an existing project In grails ,so I want to know the version of grails as well as version of Groovy for that project

Comment: To get the Groovy version anywhere in the app, you can use `GroovySystem.getVersion()` or just `GroovySystem.version`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metadata regarding a project in Grails is kept in `application.properties`.

Within this file you will find the version of Grails used for the project under the key `app.grails.version`.

The version of Groovy used however is not kept in this file and is determined by the version of Grails being used. To determine the version of Groovy used by a specific version of Grails visit the [introduction section](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/guide/introduction.html) of the Grails documentation.

**edit**

As pointed out in another answer, if you have target version of Grails already downloaded you can search for the version of Groovy being used by that version of Grails.

*nix

```
$ cd grails-X.X.X 
$ find . -name "groovy*jar"
```

win32

```
> cd grails-x.x.x
> dir /s "groovy*.jar"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a project and want to learn which grails version it uses. You can find it in **gradle.properties** file.
The content of the file is like the following

```
grailsVersion=4.0.1
gorm.version=7.0.2.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 3):

From controllers/services:

```
def appVersion=Metadata.current.'app.grails.version'
def appName=Metadata.current.'app.name'
```

From gsp:

```
App Version <g:meta name="app.version"/> 
Built with Grails <g:meta name="app.grails.version"/>
```

Added extra information to figure out a grails application version from raw text files :

If you have a grails 3 application, you should find a build.gradle in the main root of your application folder:

[version "0.1"](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testads/blob/master/build.gradle#L16)   According to this grails 3 project the version of this application is 0.1

Grails version is [3.1.1](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testads/blob/master/gradle.properties) according to gradle.properties

On a grails 2 project you will find application.properties in the main project root:

According to this grails 2 project

grails version is [2.4.4](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testad/blob/master/application.properties#L3)
App version is [0.1](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testad/blob/master/application.properties#L5)

Comment: I get the error `No such property: Metadata for class` for `appVersion`

Comment: the above was for grails 2 are you using it on grails 3 ? https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/meta.html

Comment: if i knew which version of grails i used then i would not look at this question. The link you gave only shows printing for GSP not for controllers.

Comment: @kiltek take a look at my updated answer, its how you manually can find all that out

Answer (score 1):

As of Grails 3, this is:

```
Version <g:meta name="info.app.version"/>
```

Notice the *info*.
http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/ref/Tags/meta.html

Answer (score 0):

use `application.properties` in the root of the grails application

Answer (score 0):

To find out which version of groovy is used with particular version of grails I always use simple find:

```
$ cd grails-X.X.X 
$ find . -name "groovy*jar"
```

Maybe I'm just too lazy to dig into websites... ;-)

Comment: Assuming 1. You are running *nix and 2. You have the version of Grails downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can see **application name,grails version,application version** from **application.properties** file of grails project

Answer (score -2):

I face the same issue, I found simplest way to find version by simple command.
run

```
grails clean
```

then it prints
**Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/**

Comment: This is the version of Grails currently in use on the command line, not the version required by a project.